# AS3, adding variable to function name

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables, actionscript

I have 6 functions, called callClip1, callClip2, callClip3 and so on.

I had planned on writing out 6 else/if statements to call each of these when I need to, but I thought it could (possibly) be done another way. Could I call one function called "callClip" and add a variable to the end of it that I set elsewhere? So if the variable was set to 3, it would put callClip + 3 together and call that function?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be done with a switch block:

Used as:  `callClip(1);`

```
function callClip(number:int):void
{
    switch(number)
    {
        case 1:
            callClip1();
            break;
        case 2:
            callClip2();
            break;
        case 3:
            callClip3();
            break;
        case 4:
            callClip4();
            break;
        case 5:
            callClip5();
            break;
        case 6:
            callClip6();
            break;
    }
}
```

Although I wouldn't recommend it, this could also be implemented as:

```
function callClip(number:int):void
{
    this["callClip" + number]();
}
```

Comment: Nice I was just about to suggest your second idea, and also would not recommend it :)

Comment: Agree I think generally though instead of having a bunch of functions there should probably just be one that has this type of switch in it to change the functionality rather than having a bunch of copies of a function and the need to both update the switch statement and create the new function.  Good answer if there's a good reason to be doing this (like callClip1-6 all have very variable functionality within them).

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jason's answer, you could also do this:

```
// Store references to each method.
var methods:Vector.<Function> = new <Function>[
    callClip1, callClip2, callClip3,
    callClip4, callClip5, callClip6
];


// Call relevant callClip function.
function callClip(num:int):void
{
    methods[num-1]();
}
```